# Warning when trying to require a module which is not installed but not necessary

Tags: javascript, webpack, require

I am trying to require a module in a file that would be used only if the module is actually available. So the module is totally optional. This code will be distributed as part of a 3rd party library. The issue is that any user using webpack will see their build fail if I use `import`, so I ended up using:

```
let webrtc = {};
try {
  webrtc = require('my-optional-module');
} catch (err) {}
```

But even with this code, they will get a warning on projects that don't need this optional module:

```
[WEB] WARNING in ./node_modules/xxx
[WEB] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'my-optional-module' in '/Users/xxx/node_modules/xxx'
```

**Edit: Using the answer below**

```
let webrtc = {};
if(require.resolve('my-optional-module')) {
  webrtc = require('my-optional-module');
}
```

But I get this warning:

```
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

And this error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'my-optional-module' in xxx
```

**Edit2:**

Based on [webpack instruction](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-) to do dynamic imports, I also tried:

```
var webrtc = {};
require.ensure(['my-optional-module'], function (require) {
  return webrtc = require('my-optional-module');
});
```

But I still get:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'my-optional-module' in xxx
```

Comment: What's wrong with a warning? It still compiles, and it's a valid notice for something that could be considered a legitimate mistake. According to [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/339), using a `try` / `catch` as in your first attempt will successfully bundle it as an optional import

Comment: Because it is supposed to be part of a third party library. It is not very cool to pollute the users with unnecessary warnings...

Comment: @Sharcoux What solution did you come up with?

Comment: From what I remember, I just let the warning.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like [this is a common issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/196) in webpack. According to the [configuration docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#module-contexts), you can use the flag `module: { exprContextCritical: false }` in your `webpack.config.js` to suppress this warning globally across your project, though the flag is considered deprecated and you may find more highly recommended solutions in the [issue I linked](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/196).

Comment: Ok, but as a 3rd party library, I won't be able to access the webpack config of my users... Most of the solutions I found in your link will also meet the same requirement...

Comment: I may have misread, but my understanding was that these configurations were intended for 3rd party libraries. When you say 3rd party, do you mean you anticipate end developers to include your source as part of their output bundles?

Comment: I'm not sure if I correctly understood your question, but the idea is that I provide a node module that people can use (`npm install my-module`). But if they use webpack as I do in my own projects (projects depending on `my-module`), and if they don't need `my-optional-module`, they will get a useless and annoying warning.

Comment: So you expect users to `require()` your module, and allow webpack to include it in the output bundle, like I was asking. In that case, there's currently no way to disable that warning without access to the `webpack.config.js`. You should probably mention the optional dependency in your documentation so that developers aren't alarmed by the output warning.

Comment: That sucks... But ok, then. I hope this might evolve.